# Rally Milestones Report

Tags: rally

I have a 'Milestone Status' Rally view with below columns and want to extract the same in excel format. There are two Rally Workspaces created (say A and B), There is one 'feature' created in one Rally workspace (A); however the **LINKED** user stories, tasks and defects are created in other Rally workspace (B). I can view all the **Linked** user stories, tasks, defects linked into that feature created in the workspace (A) itself.

When I use the default extract option from Rally workspace (A), I am able to extract however it only give me single line of data which is the 'feature'. As I understand, this is because I am extracting from workspace (A) in which the feature is created; however I want to extract the entire items liked to the feature from Workspace (A) itself.

Can you please help in how to extract the entire report using one workspace to get all the required columns?

Regards,
Rahul W.

Comment: The columns are; Formatted ID
Name
Actual End Date
Actual Start Date
Defect Status
Estimate
Feature
Iteration
Owner
Parent
Percent Done By Story Count
Percent Done By Story Plan Estimate
Plan Estimate
Planned End Date
Planned Start Date
Portfolio Item Type
Project
Priority
Release
Resolution
Severity
State
Tags
Target Build
Target Date
Submitted By
Task Estimate Total
Task Status
Test Case Result
Time Spent
To Do
Task Remaining Total
UserStories
Work Product

Comment: It is impossible to have artifacts in one workspace attached to or referencing artifacts in another...

Comment: What is the best way to extract and collate the required data in excel from different workspaces? Can I use the Rally Excel add in tool; connect to different workspaces and extract the data in separate spreadsheets and then merge data into one spreadsheet?

Comment: I am unfortunately not an expert at the Excel connector.  I am pretty sure you do have the ability to select workspaces there though. I'd suggest reaching out to Rally support with your question and see what they recommend.